# Duplicate request at same time in Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I am facing an issue of duplicate requests for single API,
I am using retrofit 2.When i try to call one API, 3 times its hitting the server.
same API is called multiple times with in fraction of sections. Here is the code:

```
 public Retrofit retrofit() {
    String UrlBasePath="";

    if (mRetrofit == null) {
        if (builder == null) {
            builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        builder.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request original = chain.request();
                HttpUrl httpUrl = original.url().newBuilder()
                        .build();
                String credentials = BuildConfig.ApiUserName + ":" + BuildConfig.ApiPassword;

                if (BuildConfig.ApiUserName.equals("APIUSERNAME") || BuildConfig.ApiPassword.equals("APIPASSWORD")) {
                    AnalyticsManager.sendEvent("RETROERROR", "AUTHENTICATIONFAILED", "FAILED");
                }

                final String basic = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
                // Request customization: add request headers
                Request request = original.newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Authorization", basic)
                        .addHeader("User-Agent", "android")
                        .method(original.method(), original.body())
                        .url(httpUrl)
                        .build();
                return chain.proceed(request);

            }
        }).connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        if(BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE.equalsIgnoreCase("debug")) {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        builder.addInterceptor(logging);
        }

        UrlBasePath = UrlParser.httpsUrlBasePath;

        OkHttpClient client = enableTls12OnPreLollipop(builder).build();

        mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(UrlBasePath)
                .addConverterFactory(new ToStringConverterFactory())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gsonMapper()))
                .client(client)
                .build();
    }
    }
    return mRetrofit;
}
```

Called this method in Activity: Activity code

```
private final BmApiInterface RetroApiCall = RetroConnect.getInstance().retrofit().create(BmApiInterface.class); //global variable

Call<SingleLoginParser> loginCall = RetroApiCall.getLoginAPI(MatriidDet+"~"+Constants.APPVERSIONCODE,System.currentTimeMillis(),
                        Constants.constructApiUrlMap(new UrlParser().UrlGenerator(Constants.COMMON_LOGIN, new String[]{}))
                );
                mCallList.add(loginCall);
                RetroConnect.getInstance().AddToEnqueue(loginCall, mListener, RequestType.COMMON_LOGIN);
```

Can some one help me!!

Comment: can you share the code where you are calling  this class to get retrofit?

Comment: activity code added above..

Comment: @sree : Did you find the solution for it? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @Jatin, No i didn't found any solution..

Answer (score 7):

It possible when server response is slow and timeout then retfofit2 retry same request multiple times. To prevent this you have to use `.retryOnConnectionFailure(false)`method with OkHttpClient.

Sample code :

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient= null;
        okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .sslSocketFactory(new TLSSocketFactory(),trustManager)
                .connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .writeTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                //.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustManager)
                .followRedirects(false)
                .followSslRedirects(false)
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
                .cache(null)//new Cache(sContext.getCacheDir(),10*1024*1024)
                .build();
```

In previous version have some bugged and fixed after retrofit:2.1.0

So you should use updated version of retrofit2 and okhttp3:

```
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
```

Issue discussion:

https://github.com/square/okhttp/pull/1259#issuecomment-68430264